# sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory when Loading items in a streambuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, memory, stream, infinite-scroll

I have a list with many items. These Items are shown with its image and to not having problems with memory I've done a 'infinite scrolling' which the streamBuilder loads 10 items, and when user gets the bottom it loads more 10. But if I load more than 20 items, the app freezes and crashes...

This is the method to get the items from Firebase:

```dart
  Future<void> loadnovo(
      {String submenu,
        int limit = 10,
        bool limpar = false,
        bool carregamentoInicial = false,
        int lastIndex}) async {
    if (limpar) {
      conteudo.clear();
      hasMore = true;
    }

    _isLoading = true;

    var parts = submenu.split('/');
    var pathSlashless = parts[0].trim();
    var subPathSlashless = parts.sublist(1).join('/').trim();

    var snapshot = await _storage.ref().child("/${submenu}");
    var retorno = await snapshot.listAll();

    if (subPathSlashless.isEmpty || subPathSlashless == null) {
      retorno.prefixes.forEach((element) {
        conteudo.add(
          ItemLab(
            tipo: 'PASTA',
            elemento: element,
          ),
        );
        _streamController.add(conteudo);
      });
    }

    for (int i = lastIndex; i < lastIndex + limit; i++) {
      var url = await retorno.items[i].getDownloadURL();
      conteudo.add(
        ItemLab(
          tipo: 'FILE',
          elemento: retorno.items[i],
          imageUrl: url,
        ),
      );
      _streamController.add(conteudo);

    }

    hasMore = true;

    if (subPathSlashless.isNotEmpty) {
      List items;
      await databaseReference
          .collection("lab_${pathSlashless}_url")
          .snapshots()
          .forEach((element) {
        element.docs.forEach((f) {
          if (f.data()['videos'] != null) {
            items == null
                ? items = f.data()['videos']
                : items.addAll(f.data()['videos']);
          }
          ;
        });
      });

      for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        conteudo.add(
          ItemLab(
            tipo: 'VIDEO',
            elemento: null,
            video: items[i],
          ),
        );
        _streamController.add(conteudo);
      }
    } else {
      await databaseReference
          .collection("lab_${pathSlashless}_url")
          .snapshots()
          .forEach((element) {
        element.docs.forEach((f) async {
          if (f.data().isNotEmpty) {
            if (f.data().keys.contains("videos")) {
              conteudo.add(
                ItemLab(
                    tipo: 'PASTA',
                    pastaVideo: findFolderName(f.reference.path)),
              );
              _streamController.add(conteudo);
            } else {
              conteudo.add(
                ItemLab(
                  tipo: 'VIDEO',
                  elemento: null,
                  video: f.data(),
                ),
              );
              _streamController.add(conteudo);
            }
          }
        });
      });
    }

    pathSlashless = null;
    subPathSlashless = null;


  }
```

This is the list:

```dart
LabController ctrlLab;
  final lab = LabMdScreen();
 inal scrollController = ScrollController();
  int lastIndex = 0;

  scrollListener() async {
    if (scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent == scrollController.offset) {
      lastIndex += 10;
      ctrlLab.loadList(submenu: "ph/Res", lastIndex: lastIndex);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    ctrlLab = LabController();
    ctrlLab.loadList(submenu: "ph/Res", lastIndex: lastIndex,cls: true, initialLoad: true);

    scrollController.addListener(scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scrollController.removeListener(scrollListener);
    super.dispose();
  }


  loadBasicStructureDetail(submenu ,callback, context, deviceSize){
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: ctrlLab.stream,
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
          print(snapshot.error);
          return Center(child: Text('Ocorreu um erro!'));
        }else {
          return GridView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            controller: scrollController,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length +1,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {

              path = callback;
              if (i < snapshot.data.length) {
                ItemLab item = snapshot.data[i];
              
                return Dismissible(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                  background: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    color: Colors.grey[800],
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.delete,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 40,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
                  
                  },
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 5.0,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: GridTile(
                          child: Hero(
                            tag: "${item}",
                            child: item.imageUrl == null
                                ? setIconLab(item)
                                : CachedNetworkImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              imageUrl: setIconLab(item),
                              placeholder: (ctx, url) =>
                                  Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                              errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                  Image.asset('assets/images/semfoto.jpg',
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover),
                            ),
                          ),
                          footer: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  item.elemento == null
                                      ? item.video['nome']
                                      : item.elemento.name,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Theme
                                        .of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .caption
                                        .color,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () async {

                      String url = item.elemento == null ? await item
                          .video["url"] :
                      await item.elemento.getDownloadURL();
                      ctrlLab.openImage(url);
                    },
                  ),
                );

              }else if (ctrlLab.hasMore) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32.0),
                  child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                );
              } else {
                return SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                );
              }
            },
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCountAndLoading(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length +1,
              crossAxisCount: deviceSize.width < 600 ? 2 : 3,
              childAspectRatio: 0.7,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            ),
          );
```

How to avoid this problem and be able to load all the items from that folder without memory problems

Error when closes the app:

```
W/Adreno-GSL(30159): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2021>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
E/Adreno-GSL(30159): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2125>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
F/libc    (30159): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x7ce5f818 in tid 30195 (1.raster)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Lenovo/karate/K33a48:7.0/NRD90N/K33_S231_171114_ROW:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 30159, tid: 30195, name: 1.raster  >>> com.example.app_md <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x7ce5f818
    r0 48e09801  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
    r4 7ce5f810  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
    r8 00000000  r9 7bb59700  sl 00000000  fp 00000000
    ip 00000000  sp 88d84e08  lr 987fa495  pc 987fa554  cpsr 600f0030
backtrace:
    #00 pc 001d9554  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN10A5xContext25HwPatchForDirectRenderingEP15EsxRenderBucketP13EsxLinkedListj+307)
    #01 pc 000bf5cb  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN10EsxContext23PatchForDirectRenderingEP15EsxRenderBucketP13EsxLinkedListj+10)
    #02 pc 000c5031  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN10EsxContext25ProcessAndSubmitRenderingE14EsxFlushReason+1392)
    #03 pc 00147553  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN9EsxCmdMgr5FlushE14EsxFlushReason+722)
    #04 pc 000c29fd  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN10EsxContext11SwapBuffersEPK7EsxRectj+92)
    #05 pc 0012deab  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN10EglContext11SwapBuffersEPK7EsxRectj+74)
    #06 pc 001393af  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN16EglWindowSurface27PerformContextSwapOperationEP10EglContextPK7EsxRectjP21EglResourceAccessInfo+46)
    #07 pc 00139441  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN16EglWindowSurface11SwapBuffersEP10EglContextPK7EsxRectj+32)
    #08 pc 0012a8af  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN6EglApi11SwapBuffersEPvS0_+110)
    #09 pc 0000d20f  /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglSwapBuffersWithDamageKHR+290)
    #10 pc 00000fdb  /data/app/com.example.app_md-1/lib/arm/libflutter.so (offset 0x1002000)
Lost connection to device.
```

Comment: Can you share the entire gridview Widget? I believe the problem is coming from there.

Comment: Ok, wait a minute

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Found something?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. It looks fine.

Is it possible that the one or more of the images that you are loading are extremely high resolution? This will explain out of memory error.